# Order of repetition per row and column in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to figure the order of repetition per-row and just couldn't do it. Ok. Lets consider a ndarray of size `(2, 11, 10)`

```
a = np.array([
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
    ]
])
```

What I wanted to is to get the order of every `1's` per row based on a column. Whenever the first `1` is found in a row the order starts would start at `0`; then goes to the second row if `1` is found here then the order is `1`, but if the `1` is already present at the column index in the previous row, then it is ignored. For example

Lets consider these lists:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   -> column index
0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], -> no 1's no order here
1 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], -> order starts at 0
2 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], -> order starts at 1
```

At row index `0` there are no `1` so nothing happens, at row index `1` there are ones in column index `[0,1,5,6,7]` this will be equal to `0`; the output should be

```
column   order
0         0
1         0
2         -
3         -
4         -   
5         0
6         0
7         0
8         -
9         -
```

At row index `2` there are `1` at column index `[1,5,8]` whos order is `1`; in there `1` and `5` are ignored because it already has an order `0` to it, but for the unknown order it should be `1`; the final output should be

```
column   order
0         0
1         0
2         -
3         -
4         -   
5         0
6         0
7         0
8         1
9         -
```

I have tried using Numpy's `np.where` method to the index values; something like this

```
index = np.asarray(np.where(a == 1)).T
```

I have no idea what to do next. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Would you mind if I ask why you're looking to do this? I don't think the question is unclear at all. I just can't think of what you'd be doing with this

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you also shared the overall goal of this, what are these arrays actually?

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r this is for a Spiking Neural Networks encoder. It uses one of this algorithm to get the spike times.

Comment: @Bemmu there the columns are the input neurons to in an SNN architecture and the rows are the time.

Comment: After reading this I still couldn't quite understand what "order of repetition per-row" means

Comment: @Bemmu Maybe I should change it to something like "Order of 1's in a row based on previous row"?

Comment: Trying to read this makes my brain hurt and makes me want to give up. I don't really know what to ask to help you improve it because I can't get a grasp of it at all :P

Comment: Well first of all, so is the goal to map each row to a number somehow?

Comment: @Bemmu yes yes and ignore the repeated ones.

Comment: You have two 2D arrays. Do those two 2D arrays somehow depend on each other?

Comment: Your first example `a` is three dimensional.  How is that relevant?  Do you want to apply this order assignment to each of the 2-d arrays `a[0]` and `a[1]`?

Comment: @Bemmu No they are not. Both are very much different from each other

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes exactly that.

Comment: In general, will every column have at least one 1 in it?

Comment: Would this be the correct answer for the first 2D array? [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser no its not compulsory; its all by chance.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the answer for the first array, `a[0]` is `[0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4]`.  Is that correct?

Comment: In your example you say "At row index 1 there are 1 at column index [1,5,8]", are you sure you don't mean row index 2?

Comment: *"its all by chance"*  In that case, you have to specify what value should be in the result when a column is all zeros.  Currently it is undefined.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser and @Bemmu Its actually `[0,0,4,4,3,0,0,0,2,7]` you'll have to consider the first row as well.

Comment: If you have to consider the first row, then why aren't the first two values `1`?  It looks like you simply want the row index of the first 1 in each column.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes. Why didn't I think of it? Yes. Thats what I was looking for.

Comment: But you still have to figure out what you want if a column is all zeros.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes. I have no idea How I would do that

Comment: @akshay Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the desired result--based on comments on the question and an earlier version of this answer--is to find the "dense ranking" of the row index of the first 1 in each column.  (See the docstring of [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) for the meaning of "dense ranking".)   The result can be found using a combination of the `.argmax()` method and `scipy.stats.rankdata`.

Here's a function that computes the order for a two-dimensional array.  The question doesn't define what should happen when a column is all zeros; `order` assigns that column the value -1.

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

def order(x):
    result = x.argmax(axis=0)
    result[(x == 0).all(axis=0)] = -1
    rank = rankdata(result, method='dense') - 1 - np.any(result < 0)
    return rank
```

For example, here is the array `y`:

```
In [71]: y
Out[71]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [72]: order(y)
Out[72]: array([ 1,  0,  1,  2,  0,  0,  3, -1])
```

Here's the array `a` from the question:

```
In [73]: a
Out[73]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]])
```

The function `order()` expects a two-dimensional array, so we must use a loop to get the order for each subarray in `a`:

```
In [74]: np.array([order(m) for m in a])
Out[74]: 
array([[0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4],
       [2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: @akshay Very curious to hear if this is correct, as I still don't understand the problem statement :D

Comment: This answer is not right actually; the order for `a[0]` is `[0,0,3,3,2,0,0,0,1,4] `. Sorry @WarrenWeckesser.

Comment: That's the order that I proposed in a comment five hours ago!  I'll update my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @akshay In the meantime, *please* edit the question to clarify what you are trying to compute, and include that expected order for `a[0]` in the question.  If you can, also try to figure out what you want to do when a column is all zeros.  How to handle that case might be determined by what you are going to do with the order.  In my current answer, I put -1 just to do *something*, but we have really have no idea what should happen in that case.

Comment: @akshay The answer is updated.

Comment: YESSS!! That's what I wanted. Thank you so much for the help. I will update my question.